# Android studio can't override default theme

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to assign a theme to a button with a custom background. It looks simply like this:

```
<style name="button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/buttonbackground</item>
</style>‌

<Button android:theme="@style/button"/>
```

The button keeps it's original background, but for TextView, for example, it works.

```
<TextView android:theme="@style/button"/>
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: You could simplify your problem further and try `<Button android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"/>`. If that does work, then the problem is somehting to do with styles. If that doesn't work then the problem is with the attributes (in that you are using the wrong one)

Comment: Are you using Material Theme or App Compat  Theme?

Comment: @Blundell This works with the app theme I'm currently using, but when I used the default one (Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar), that did not work either. The problem is definitely with styles, because when I delete the app theme, the button works. But obviously the app then looks like crap.

Comment: @Pinakin I'm using the Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Answer (score 0):

change your app theme:

```
    <style name="Theme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge">
        .....
    </style>
```

use @style/Theme in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme"
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was a very simple solution, just use `style` instead of `android:theme`. I just didn't know it existed.